# What will happen if my class conforms to two protocols having same property?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, objective-c-protocol

Let's say I have two protocols

```
@protocol Playlist<NSObject>
@property(nonatomic, copy) NSString *title;
@property(nonatomic, assign) NSUInteger trackCount;
@end
```

and another as

```
@protocol Album<NSObject>
@property(nonatomic, copy) NSString *name;
@property(nonatomic, assign) NSUInteger trackCount;
@end
```

and there is a class which conforms to these protocols

.h file

```
@interface MusicLibrary <Playlist, Album>
@end
```

.m file

```
@implementation MusicLibrary
@synthesize title;
@synthesize name;
@synthesize trackCount;
@end
```

Which trackCount property will it refer to? Can I use trackCount twice?

It surely do not give any compile time error.

Comment: it is not refering to any of them, it is a protocol it just implements that variable, it just works

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Won't it have any ambiguity?

Comment: it will probably cause some problems in this case but you need to think again about your app design

Comment: Compiler will synthesize it once with same name variable. It wont allow the synthesize twice. It will refer only lastest Protocol declaration. As per I know.

Comment: Hey @AnilGupta , thanks for explanation. I guess its correct. Did you came across any Apple document for it?

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that you are modeling your data wrong.  The way you have it setup a musicLibrary is BOTH a playlist and an album. I think a more correct model would have a MusicLibrary containing many playlist and many albums.  Something like:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray<Album>* albums;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray<Playlist>* playlists;
```

Comment: Hey Jon, thanks for the reply. Yes, it would surely solve my problem. However I want to understand how objective-C compiler would treat this scenario?

Comment: A protocol is a promise that the class makes that it will implement methods.  So MusicLibrary is making two promises.  One that it has a 'title' and 'trackCount' property and another that it has a 'name' and a 'trackCount' property.  So when MusicLibrary implements 'title', 'name' and 'trackCount' it fulfills all of its promises.  There is only one 'trackCount' property belonging to the class. The protocol doesn't have (aka implement) any property - it is just a a promise that the class will have those properties.